# How to import code from private GitHub repo into snips?

Tags: voice-recognition, snips, conversational-ui

I understand that the normal way to use complex action code in Snips is to place the code in GitHub and pull it from there via Action Type "GitHub".

Is there any way to access a private GitHub repo for this purpose?

If this is not possible, what would be the normal way to use complex action code that cannot be published?

Regarding the "Code Snippets" the documentation says "It is meant for quick testing, or simple interactions." In what respect can Code Snippets support only "simple interactions" ?

[image: Action Types in Snips]

Answer (score 2):

You need to make your repo public in order to link it with your console assistant, and code snippets are limited to Python action code. If these are not an option for you you could also make your code run locally by either:

- executing it manually (just launch your script, which listens to the MQTT communications via your code or by using Hermes)
- placing it in /var/snips/skills and making it executable if you're on Linux. The snips-skill-server will look into this directory at boot and execute any executable file that starts with "action-". See the [documentation](https://docs.snips.ai/articles/console/actions/actions/code-your-action/action-specifications)